# How do we standardize arrays with NaN?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, normalization

I used StandardScaler() to standardize data so far, but this doesn't work with NaNs. None of the other methods I know of (MinMaxScaler, RobustScaler, MaxAbsScaler) work with NaNs either. Are there other methods?

My search results came up with a solution

```
df['col']=(df['col']-df['col'].min())/(df['col'].max()-df['col'].min())
```

But this works only with panda dataframes (they have column names). Is there a way to implement column headers in the matrix?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data = pd.DataFrame({'sepal_length': [3.4, 4.5, 3.5], 
                     'sepal_width': [1.2, 1, 2],
                'petal_length': [5.5, 4.5, 4.7],
                'petal_width': [1.2, 1, 3],
                    'species': ['setosa', 'verginica', 'setosa']})

#Shuffle the data and reset the index
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
data = shuffle(data).reset_index(drop = True)  

#Create Independent and dependent matrices
X = data.iloc[:, [0, 1, 2, 3]].values 
y = data.iloc[:, 4].values

#train_test_split
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1, random_state = 0)


#Impute missing values at random
prop = int(X_train.size * 0.5) #Set the % of values to be replaced
prop1 = int(X_test.size * 0.5)

a = [random.choice(range(X_train.shape[0])) for _ in range(prop)] #Randomly choose indices of the numpy array
b = [random.choice(range(X_train.shape[1])) for _ in range(prop)]
c = [random.choice(range(X_test.shape[0])) for _ in range(prop)] #Randomly choose indices of the numpy array
d = [random.choice(range(X_test.shape[1])) for _ in range(prop)]
X_train[a, b] = np.NaN
X_test[c, d] = np.NaN
```

This is where I get the error :**Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').**

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler #importing the library that does feature scaling

```
sc_X = StandardScaler() # created an object with the scaling class

X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)  # Here we fit and transform the X_train matrix
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)
```

Answer (score 8):

This is no longer the case; as of sklearn 0.20.0, missing values are ignored in such preprocessors' `fit` and silently passed along in their `transform`:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.20.html#id37 (fourth bullet)
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10404

Answer (score 6):

Standardizing (subtracting mean and dividing by standard deviation for each column), can be done using numpy:

```
Xz = (X - np.nanmean(X, axis=0))/np.nanstd(X, axis=0)
```

where X is a matrix (containing NaNs), and Xz is the standardized version of X. Hope this helps.

EDITED:

For a test/training scenario, the mean and std could be stored in respective variables:

```
m         = np.nanmean(X_train, axis=0)
s         = np.nanstd(X_train, axis=0)
X_train_z = (X_train - m)/s 
X_test_z  = (X_test - m)/s
```

Comment: at test data time, what does one do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html).

Demo:

```
from sklearn import datasets as ds
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# load Iris data set    
data = ds.load_iris()

X = data.data
y = data.target

# artificially set 33% of [X] data set to NaN's    
X.ravel()[np.random.choice(X.size, int(X.shape[0]*.33), replace=False)] = np.nan
```

yields:

```
In [137]: X
Out[137]:
array([[5.1, 3.5, nan, nan],
       [nan, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.7, nan, 1.3, 0.2],
       ...,
       [6.5, 3. , nan, 2. ],
       [6.2, 3.4, 5.4, 2.3],
       [5.9, 3. , nan, 1.8]])
```

now we can impute and standardize it:

```
imp = Imputer(strategy="mean", axis=0)
scale = StandardScaler()

In [139]: X_new = scale.fit_transform(imp.fit_transform(X))
```

result:

```
In [160]: X_new
Out[160]:
array([[-1.03733263e+00,  1.22587069e+00, -1.37398311e-15, -3.17837019e-16],
       [ 1.18191646e-15, -5.32987255e-02, -1.43399195e+00, -1.35522269e+00],
       [-1.56962048e+00,  2.27226133e-15, -1.49587065e+00, -1.35522269e+00],
       ...,
       [ 8.25674859e-01, -5.32987255e-02, -1.37398311e-15,  1.22131653e+00],
       [ 4.26458969e-01,  9.70036804e-01,  1.04115598e+00,  1.65073974e+00],
       [ 2.72430791e-02, -5.32987255e-02, -1.37398311e-15,  9.35034396e-01]])
```

---

Demo2, using Pipeline:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer, StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

#...    

estimator = Pipeline([("impute", Imputer(strategy="mean", axis=0)),
                      ("scale", StandardScaler()),
                      ("forest", RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0,
                                                       n_estimators=100))])

estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
#...
```

Comment: The code runs, but it there a way to perform fit_transform for this?

Comment: @uharsha33, sure you can. Just don't stack it in a pipeline and use `Imputer(...).fit_transform()` separately...

Comment: My coding skills are pretty limited, would be helpful if you could show me a demo. Also, my y_train wouldn't need imputation as it doesn't have any missing values. And when i tried **estimator.fit(X_train)**, it threw up an error about singleton array

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited the question as you've suggested.

Comment: @uharsha33, please test you script, i'm getting: `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

Comment: @ MaxU It should run now, forgot to add the 'species' column

Comment: in demo1 Stadardization/normalization hasn’t been done. This is imp since the imputation method I’m planning to use is KNN which performs better with normalization. Also the normalization must be done after the missing values have been artificially imputed with NaNs. This is where I’m facing an issue, as none of the scaling methods with a package ignore NaN values.

Comment: @uharsha33, check updated answer...

Answer (score 1):

Working with NaNs is always a bit difficult. Maybe it would be useful if you try to enrich NaN values. For example, by averaging the considered feature for groups like an age class. If only a few records have NaN values, you might simply drop these (pandas dropna).

Comment: dropping rows is out of question. My dataset has 50% missing values.